# How to create seed data for an intermediate table that matches another 2 tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I have 2 models, Photo and Album.

To match them, I did an intermediate table, `Photo_Listings`, that has `photo_id` and `album_id` columns.

But, when trying to seed the ddbb, I get the following problem:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `photo_listing' for #<Album:0x00000109698318>
```

In my seeds, I want to create some albums, and also some photo listings so that the albums have some photos inside.

```
  15.times do
    album = Album.create do |w|
      w.title = Faker::Commerce.product_name
      w.description = Faker::Lorem.sentence
      w.user_id = rand(1..4)
    end
    album.photo_listing.create do |w|
      w.photo_id = rand(1..10)
      w.album_id = rand(1..10)
    end
  end
```

My Photo_listings model

```
class PhotoListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

Comment: Change `album.photo_listing` to `album.photo_listings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You need to call table as `plural` but not `singular`

Change `album.photo_listing` to `album.photo_listings`

It will Work.